# Escape captured expression with PHP preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, ckeditor

I am struggling with `preg_replace` and am really hoping someone can spot my error. Regular expressions seem to be my Achilles heel.

I'm trying to replace strings like `{{123.jpg}}` with `<img src="http://mydomain/some/path/123.jpg"></img>`

I searched similar questions and found `preg_quote`, but I don't believe I have any regex characters in the non-regex part of my replacement string, so I'm at a loss.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
function replace($article_id,$text){
    $pattern = '/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/';
    $replacement = '<img src="'.URL_CONSTANT.'articles/'.$article_id.'/'.'${1}'.'"></img>';
    return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
}
```

I can confirm that the pattern is matching, but it's not replacing properly. I think the issue may relate to the final `/` before the `${1}` replacement, but I don't see why as I don't believe it's a special regex character.

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT: I discovered the issue was unrelated to my expression. Thanks to everyone who assisted in verifying that my expression was properly formed!**

Comment: [It appears to work fine for me](http://codepad.org/KLNt2JSr). What replacing problems are you encountering?

Comment: @alex Interesting. Thanks for taking the time to test. I wonder if the issue occurs when the text is re-interpreted. I am intercepting input into CKEditor and replacing image shortcuts with full image tags.

Comment: If you can reproduce the issue on http://codepad.org, link me and I'll take another look. Also, `{$1}` is fine for back references, it reduces ambiguity too.

Comment: There is no `<img></img>`, it is a single tag: `<img />`.

Comment: @baz Thank you! My HTML's a little rusty. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Thanks both of you. I discovered the issue was the "scayt" autocorrect plugin for CKEditor. It was turning the {{124.jpg}} shortcut tags into spans because it detected them as misspelled words. Disabling scayt was the solution.

Comment: @Christopher Armstrong: Suggest you post that as the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to all who helped! I discovered the issue wasn't the regular expression, but rather was the "scayt" autocorrect plugin for CKEditor. It was turning the {{124.jpg}} shortcut tags into spans because it detected them as misspelled words. I wrote another regular expression which removed these spans and replaced them with the original {{abc.def}} format. This seems to have solved the problem.